# Icon with Fluutter Background Service is Different

Tags: flutter, background-service, appicon

I'm using 'flutter_background_service' package with Flutter to run a service in the background, when setting up the I need to configure the Notification Channel.

The notification is now being shown but the title and description I set but the App icon is different than my App icon; how can fix this and make it show my real app icon?

[image: Text]

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service#android

To change notification icon, just add drawable icon with name ic_bg_service_small.
read also th warning

Comment: should this icon be of .png extension? and should I place it in 'assets' folder or in one of 'res' directory folders?